# overlay multi scaled image and video into video with ffmepg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a trouble that I want to merge 3 scaled image and 1 mp4 video into a video.
Just like camtasia. 3 images that I scaled and overlay somewhere on the video. The output is a video that has 3 images on.

Thank you for helping.

Image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o8PG.jpg)

I need to render 1 video with texts and images scaled. All in the border.

Comment: I have a command like that. But I dont know how to make it work with background is video and 2 image on it.
ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\dangk\Desktop\Videos\Anh Mo - Anh Khang.mp4" -i "C:\Users\dangk\Desktop\Image\_MG_8277.Jpeg" -i "C:\Users\dangk\Desktop\Image\giphy.gif" -filter_complex [1]scale=320:240[b];[2]scale=120:80[w];[b][w]overlay=5:H-h-5[v] -map "[v]" "C:\Users\dangk\Desktop\Image\output.mp4"

Comment: Your question is vague. Add an example image that shows what you want to do.

Comment: i added image. please help me